# Code Project Open License linking restrictions

Tags: open-source-software

The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Project_Open_License) for the [Code Project Open License](https://www.codeproject.com/info/cpol10.aspx) lists "Linking from code with a different license" as "Unclear". It seems unambiguous to me: code with a different license could link CPOL-licensed code with the restriction that the combined program not be used for "illegal, immoral or improper purposes" (CPOL 5.f.), so any code under a license that allows this added restriction could link it without issues.

Is this interpretation right, or is it more complicated than that? I haven't been able to find a definitive answer on the Code Project forums or elsewhere.

Comment: CPOL 5.f is legally a waste of space - no software can be used for illegal purposes legally and immoral or improper are legally undefinable

Comment: [According to the founder of CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/suggestions.aspx?msg=4469912), the immorality part at least was added because of instances where developers successfully sued users of their code for using it in immoral ways, so I _think_ that 5.f. is supposed to make it easier for the code's authors to sue in those cases. But then he goes on to talk about dropping that clause and getting a "moral rights release" from authors instead, which sounds like it would do the opposite.

Comment: It looks like the founder is confusing "moral rights" under copyright law (which are legally defensible) with immorality which is an ethical position with no legal substance.